# ReactJS - How to re-render functional component after POST data to database

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I am building a blogging application. This application has frontend built with ReactJS and backend built with Python (Django Framework). The frontend and backend are connected with Django REST API Framework.

This post is on ReactJS Frontend.

I am using Functional Component. There is a "BlogList" Component where all blogs fetched from API endpoints will be displayed. I created a "BlogForm" Component where I have to enter 2 fields: "Title" and "Content" to create blog post. I imported the "BlogForm" Component inside "BlogList" Component to show it on the same page.
[Please see this image to get a good understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz0Df.png)

When I enter "Title" and "Content" inside "BlogForm" Component and click on "Submit" button, data is saved in database using API call. But the added data is not showing in the "BlogList" Component at that time. I have to refresh the page to see the new blog post in the blog list.

Can anyone in the community help me to solve the problem that how can I instantly view the added blog post when I click on "Submit" button?

For your kind reference, the code is as below.

**BlogList.js**

```
import BlogForm from './BlogForm'

const BlogList = (url) => {

    
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        
        async function fetchBlogData() {
            
            const url = requests.blogList

            const request = await axios.get(url)

            setBlogs(request.data)
            return request
        }
        fetchBlogData()
    }, [url])

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <BlogWrapper className="blog">

                // Blog Form Component Added
                <BlogForm />

                <div className="blog__header">
                    <h1 className="blog__header--title">
                        Information
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <hr className="blog__divider"/>
                <div className="blog__list">
                    <ul>
                        <li className="blog__item">
                            { blogs.map( (blog) => (
                                <div className="blog__item--container" key={ blog.id }>
                                    <h1 className="blog__item--title">
                                        <a className="blog__item--title blog__item--title--link" href={`/blog/${ blog.id }`}>
                                            { blog.title }
                                        </a>
                                    </h1>
                                    <small className="blog__item--date">{ blog.date_published }</small>
                                    <p className="blog__item--content">{ blog.content }</p>
                                </div>
                            ) ) }
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </BlogWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default BlogList
```

**BlogForm.js**

```
const BlogForm = () => {

    const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
        title : '',
        content : ''
    })

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setInputValues({ ...inputValues })

        const { title, content } = inputValues
        const blogPost = { title, content }

        const url = requests.blogCreate
        const response = await axios.post(url, blogPost)
        return response
    }

    const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
        setInputValues({ ...inputValues, [name] : event.target.value })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required value={ inputValues.title } onChange={ handleChange('title') }/>
                <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Content" required value={ inputValues.content } onChange={ handleChange('content') }/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BlogForm
```

**UPDATED**

After the answer from DrewReese, I updated my code and I am getting error when I try to add a new Blog Post. It is showing `undefined` [image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate how both of these component relate to one another, how they are rendered? From what I can see you need only update the `props` object (*you named it `url` for some reason*) in `BlogList` and it should rerender and trigger the effect callback.

Comment: @DrewReese: I just import `BlogForm` Component inside `BlogList` Component.

Comment: Oh, I see now, sorry. Does the POST response have the new data you would want to render? Can you share what the GET and POST responses are?

Comment: You need some sort of callback function in BlogList that you pass down as a prop to BlogForm.

Comment: @DrewReese: Yes, the POST response have the new data. I am checking that in the backend API.

Comment: @LindaPaiste : Can you explain it with the code that I have shared in the post?

Comment: An idea: You move `fetchBlogData` out of the useEffect. Afterwards, you pass that function as a prop to `<BlogForm func={()=>fetchBlogData}/>` Then, on `handleSubmit `, call `props.func()`

Comment: Ah, I see, so perhaps that POST response *doesn't* have the data you need. Can you share what the GET ***and*** POST responses are. You may just need to massage or access the response data a specific way.

Comment: @DrewReese : GET and POST response Status
"GET /blog-api/blogs/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"POST /blog-api/blog/create/ HTTP/1.1" 201

After clicking "Submit" button, data is successfully added in Database and POST was successful.

Comment: @NanoBit : Can you explain it with the code that I have shared in the post?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I meant the response body, not the request status, in other words, what you get in the code. Something like `console.log(request.data)` from the GET request, and `console.log(response)` from the POST request.

Comment: I got the solution. It should be response.data in POST request. Thank you so much @DrewReese

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there. I suspected it was something like that, but without seeing any hard responses I prefer to not make assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BlogList` has the state you want to be updated from the child component `BlogForm`. You can pass a callback from parent to child for `BlogForm` to call with the updated posts.

BlogList

```
const BlogList = (props) => {
    const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchBlogData() {
            const url = requests.blogList;
            const request = await axios.get(url);
            setBlogs(request.data);
        }
        fetchBlogData();
    }, [props]);

    // (1) Define a callback to update state
    const addNewPost = post => setBlogs(posts => [...posts, post]);

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <BlogWrapper className="blog">

                // Blog Form Component Added
                <BlogForm addNewPost={addNewPost} /> // <-- (2) pass callback

                ...
            </BlogWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

BlogForm

```
const BlogForm = ({ addNewPost }) => { // <-- (3) destructure callback

    const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
        title : '',
        content : ''
    })

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setInputValues({ ...inputValues });

        const { title, content } = inputValues;
        const blogPost = { title, content };

        const url = requests.blogCreate;
        const response = await axios.post(url, blogPost);
        addNewPost(response.data); // <-- (4) call callback with new post data
    }

    ...

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code explanation. I am getting `undefined` result in the page when I click "Submit" button. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @JeetZawab-UlHakimKhondker Sure, but can you point to a specific line of code where the undefined value is?

Comment: I sent you an email in your gmail. Can you please check and respond there? It will be easier to demonstrate.

Comment: @JeetZawab-UlHakimKhondker I was just asking if you could point us to the specific line of code where the undefined value is that you are seeing. If there's a stacktrace to accompany the error message that would be great. Please update your question with these new details if you can.